# AWS Application Load Balancer and Wordpress redirection

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I have an existing web-site in wordpress.  For moving to production, I created an EC2 instance and an RDS, copied the existing site to /var/www/html folder. I am using apache web-server.

Next I created a Application Load Balancer and added the EC2 instance in the target group.  My ALB listens on port 443 and redirect to port 80 on the target group.

I have changed the siteurl and home configuration in wp_options table.  After reviewing bunch of posts in stack overflow I also updated wp-config.php with the following lines at top and configured my database connection.

```
/* setup ssl */
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Finally, I migrated the old database to my new RDS instance.

Now when I go to my domain, eg., https:\my-domain-name.com, the first page displays.  But anything after that does not work.  I traced some issues to wp_posts table where the guid column was pointing to my original development site.  Updated the guid to the new site - but it did not help.  I created completely new page and published them.  It does not show up either.

What else can I try?  Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"? That doesn't give us anything to go on. Do you get an error? A blank page? The wrong page? The wrong URL? If you get an error, what *exactly* is the error you get? We are not mind readers, we can't help with a problem if you don't tell us what it is!

Comment: Sorry.  I get "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server."

Curiously though, when I do a preview, it works.  For example, https://example.net/?page_id=97&preview=true works.  But https://example.net/actualPage results in the above message.  Here actualPage has page id 97

Comment: I have resolved the issue.  For anyone in future having similar problem - the issue was redirection.  I had to change Apache httpd.conf file and update AllowOverride to All.  By default AllowOverride is set the None.